# How to compare Int value that is saved into shared preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i m trying to create Level Review and show level rating after completed beside the level image. my code is ready and showing rating after level completion 
i m saving score value into Shared Preference and checking for value 
Here is code

```html
// adding value to cookies from First Activity 
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit(); editor.putInt("level1_rating",AllGlobalVariables.level_score ); editor.putInt("level2_rating",AllGlobalVariables.level2_score );
editor.commit(); 

// calling function in Second Activity
rating(AllGlobalVariables.level1); 


//------ function defination --------//

private void rating(String l) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  int left = 15;
  int top = 65;
  int right=0;
  int bottom=0;
  lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
if(l.equals("1")){
if (sharedpreferences.contains("level1_rating"))
  {
if(AllGlobalVariables.level_score <= 50){
   
Bitmap goodbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.fail);
String goodimagecode = BitMapToStringgood(goodbmp);
Bitmap goods = StringToBitMapgoods(goodimagecode);
Drawable verticalImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), goods);
AllGlobalVariables.Rimagel1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6); AllGlobalVariables.Rimagel1.setImageDrawable(verticalImage);
       }
}
}
}
```

But PROBLEM is : i m able to get value form key but not able to compare value from Key of Shared Preference to show rating. Please Advice how to compare value from key

or there is any other idea that can do this work , Advice will be very grateful

thanks

Comment: show some related part of code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K  sure, i will post code in  a while

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K code updated, Please check

Comment: where you are getting value from Preference?

Comment: code updated , sorry it's my bad

Comment: what issue getting when using `sharedpreferences.getInt("level1_rating",0);` ??

Comment: i want to compare value in if() , but it gernating error 
if (sharedpreferences.contains("level1_rating") = 70)
and do other work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SharedPreferences.contains](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#contains%28java.lang.String%29) return `true` if preferences contains a preference otherwise `false` .

Use [SharedPreferences.getInt](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for getting integer value and then compare with other values :

```
if (sharedpreferences.contains("level1_rating"))
{
   int level1_ratingValue=sharedpreferences.getInt("level1_rating",0);;
    if(level1_ratingValue==70){
      // do work if condition true
    }else{
      // do work if condition false
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rahulkumar: still getting issue

Comment: yes, it works for first Time rating appearing but after restarting phone it will not works

Comment: @Rahulkumar: `` use `if (sharedpreferences.contains("level1_rating")){Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit(); editor.putInt("level1_rating",AllGlobalVariables.level_score ); editor.putInt("level2_rating",AllGlobalVariables.level2_score );editor.commit();}`

Comment: i have to write 'int level1_ratingValue=sharedpreferences.getInt("level1_rating",0);;'code after editor.commit(); or can u please update your code it will helpful

Comment: i think that i got what is creating issues . let me double check my project and get back to you